# Vue.js transition and GSAP3 stagger usage

Tags: vue.js, animation, transition, gsap

I'm using Vue.js and gsap for listing card elements but it is not animating one by one.
Here it is Vue.js codes:

```
<transition-group appear @before-enter="beforeEnter" @enter="enter" :css="false">
  <div class="card" v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
    <span>{{ card.name }}</span>
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

vue js and gsap parts:

```
beforeEnter(el) {
  console.log(el);
  gsap.from(el, {
    duration: 1
    opacity:0,
    ease: "power2.inOut",
    stagger: {
      grid: "auto",
      from: "start",
      amount: 1.5
    }
  })
},
enter(el, done) {
  gsap.to(el, {
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 1
  })
}
```

Animation is working but all listed at the same time. I want to be listed one by one

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the situation you're asking about. A code snippet or jsfiddle/codepen demo will make your question much more likely to be answered quickly.